# How to upload Imagefile with Ajax in struts2

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

```
function myPage() {
        var url1 = "imagefile="+"img/"+ absPath;

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "fileupload.action",
            data :  $('#uploadImagess').attr('mynewfile'),
            success : function(data) {
                alert("success Insert : "+filePath);

            },
            error : function(data) {
                alert("ERROR IN SAVE DATA");
            }

        }); 
}
```

Comment: comment this code and find solution me

Comment: how to find source file ajax throws

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     $('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
          'action': 'imageupload.action',               
      'onComplete': function(response) {            
            $('#upload').hide();
            alert("File SAVED!!");
          },
          'onStart': function() {
            $('#upload').show(); 
          }
     });
}); 
</script>
```